# How to share data or event between angularjs and angular (2-7) applications

Tags: angularjs, angular, iframe

I have parent application in angularjs, inside view I am using iframe and loading child application (angular (2-7)) in iframe. I want to capture an event or data from angular (2-7) in angularjs. 
if to use angularjs watch how to use it. kindly refer some best practice
tried capturing iframe attribute but it is not accessible in angular2 and get parent null.

what about window.postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved that using the `postMessage` function. Something like this:

`<iframe id="yourId" frameborder="0" [src]="contentUrl"></iframe>`

in the `.ts` file:

```
public sendEvent(res){

      this.iFrame = document.getElementById('yourId');
      var iWindow = (<HTMLIFrameElement>this.iFrame).contentWindow;

      iWindow.postMessage({
        'func': 'test',
        'obj': ...yourData...
      }, "*");
    }
```

the application that will catch this event has this code in the `app.component` :

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event']) yourFunction(data: any) {
  // your logic here
}
```

in the `data` you will have those values:

```
'func': 'test',
'obj': ...yourData...
```

**An important note**: using `@HostListener('window:message'` will keep the `$scope` to the component, so you can freely use `this` as you will use it normally instead of using something like `ngZone` or a `.bind(this), false`

Comment: Greate sample, But as in my case the message will be send from Angular application and than will catch it in angularjs. thanks for code. let me try this.

Comment: Let me know if you need an example or a better explanation!

Comment: Thanks it work with postmessage, What I did from angular component I set window.parent.postmessage("message","*"); and on Angularjs side I put event listner which catch this event. As your response close to my derived answer and help me to solve, I am marking your response as answer. thans @jacopo Sciampi

Comment: Well, glad that helped you ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another way can be by using `JSChannel`!

`JSChannel` supports:

- query/response
- traditional rpc query/update/response
- incremental async return of results to a query notifications
- fire and forget
- error handling